# My new installed ArcMap is blank. Re-installed many times, but did not work

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, installation, windows-11

I bought a new laptop few days ago with Windows 11. When I installed ArcGIS 10.8, something is not normal. No toolbars, no menus, nothing in the interface.
What can I do to deal with this problem?

[image]

Comment: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/system-requirements/latest/arcgis-desktop-system-requirements.htm says "Microsoft Windows 11 is supported on ArcGIS 10.8.1 and ArcGIS 10.8.2 only." Are you using one of those patches?

Comment: Also Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 or later must be installed before to installing ArcMap.

Comment: Thanks a lot！
I installed Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 or later and now problem is sloved！